# Find $f:(1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> Find $f:(1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, where
>   \begin{align*}
> &f(x) \leq \frac{x-2}{\ln 2}, \: \forall x>1 \\
> &f(x^3+1) \leq 3f(x+1), \: \forall x>0 \\
> &f(x)+f\left(\frac{x}{x-1} \right) \geq 0, \: \forall x>1
> \end{align*}

All I got, which is also obvious, is the fact that $f(2)=0$. I tried to at least guess the function, without success. Also, substituting $x \to \frac{x}{x-1}$ in the last inequality makes it unchanged, thus this doesn't help either... My last thought was that the $3$ in the second inequality getting out of the function must somehow be related to $\log$s.

As a side note, I found this as a **real analysis/calculus problem**.

Comment: Identically zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track! Let $g(x):=f(x+1)$ then the second and the third inequalities say that for all $x>0$,
$$g(x^3) \leq 3g(x), \quad
g(x)\geq -g\left(1/x \right).$$
Maybe $g$ is a logaritmic function... Let's try with $g(x)=\log_b(x)$, that is $f(x)=\log_b(x-1)$. For such $f$, the second and the third inequalities are equalities.

The first inequality says that the graph of the concave function $f$ (assume that $b>1$) is under the graph of its tangent line at $2$, i.e.  $y=(x-2)/\ln(2)$. The tangent line is
$$y=f(2)+f'(2)(x-2)=0+\frac{(x-2)}{\ln(b)}$$
Then we choose $b=2$ and $f(x)=\log_2(x-1)$ satisfies all the given inequalities.

Comment: Thank you! How about finding **all** the functions with these properties?

Comment: That's a (much?) more difficult problem.Let me think...